# OAuth2 authentication with Azure Data Factory

Tags: oauth-2.0, oracle-adf

I'm building an ETL process with ADF to extract data from YouTube API. In order to do that, the API request OAuth2 authentication. During the authentication, there is a web browser window that should be open in order to get the access key. How can I pass this window, because it is not possible to open it in ADF.